# React - how to properly make an API call and pass the result for further filtering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I use weather API for my application. The idea is to get the data from the API once as an array and pass it down for further processing. My App.js file looks like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Search from "./components/Search";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then((response) => {
      setCountries(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Search countriesList={countries} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

The Search component includes a text input field, based on which the incoming array would be filtered and dynamically displayed. However, a function responsible for filtering is not invoked.
Here are the contents of the search component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Country from "./Country";

const Search = ({ countriesList }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  console.log(countriesList);
  console.log("countries received");
  const filterCountries = (singleCountry, nameFilter) => {
    console.log("hello");
    console.log(singleCountry);
    if (singleCountry.name.toLowerCase().includes(nameFilter.toLowerCase())) {
      return singleCountry;
    }
  };

  const countryRender = (showButtonCondition, showWeatherCondition) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {countriesList
          .filter((country) => filterCountries(country, name))
          .map((filteredCountry) => (
            <Country
              key={filteredCountry.alpha3Code}
              showButton={showButtonCondition}
              showWeather={showWeatherCondition}
              countryId={filteredCountry.alpha3Code}
              countryName={filteredCountry.name}
              countryCapital={filteredCountry.capital}
              countryPopulation={filteredCountry.population}
              countryLanguages={filteredCountry.languages}
              countryFlag={filteredCountry.flag}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const nameChangeHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      search: <input value={name} onChange={nameChangeHandler} />
      <div>
        {countriesList.length > 10 || countriesList.length === 0 ? (
          <div>Too many countres, specify another filter</div>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
        {countriesList.length === 1 ? countryRender(false, true) : <></>}
        {countriesList.length > 1 && countriesList.length < 10 ? (
          countryRender(true, false)
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};    
export default Search;
```

I guess that the problem is the changing state of name (user input) that causes the whole Search component to re-render and get the full array anew, but how to overcome it? The React.memo() method doesn't seem to be applicable here, as the documentation states clearly that it shouldn't be used for preventing a component from re-rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You are never actually calling `countryRender(true, false)`. It only gets called  when `countriesList.length > 1 && countriesList.length < 10` but its length is 250.

Comment: I know, but isn't the length supposed to change when it the input country name changes?

Comment: Ok, I think I see it now, I have to filter the reults somewhere else.